# Some paths don't exist in "typesafe" repository when I use command ”sbt package“

Tags: scala, sbt

When I package the scala project using "sbt package", an error occur to me ,like this:

```
Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-git/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/0.8.5/ivys/ivy.xml
```

and I input path

```
https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-git/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/0.8.5/ivys
```

into browser I use which browse sites through proxy, it will redirect to

```
https://dl.bintray.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-git/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/0.8.5/ivys
```

I find the following path exists:

```
https://dl.bintray.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.sbt/"
```

but

```
sbt-git/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/0.8.5/
```

Doesn't the project is "marathon" which is written in Scala, the site is "https://github.com/mesosphere/marathon". I download the project, then switch into the root directory of "marathon"，and using "sbt package" commder. Are there some problem in repositories?

Comment: I am sorry the project is "marathon" which is written in Scala, the site is "https://github.com/mesosphere/marathon",  I download the project, then switch into the root directory of "marathon"，and using "sbt package" commder. I stuck in this problem for a few days.

Comment: thank you, I have ask on gitter.im/mesoscloud/marathon .

Comment: Now I solve the problem, I download jar files through a vpn software which cannot be used in linux, although sbt cannot connect an url, it will try to find  another one which can be connected through vpn. but another problem which at "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46249803/library-cannot-be-resolved" occurs to me.